# Linking QtCreator && OpenCv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, mingw, dynamic-linking

I'm having a problem linking a library from opencv(2.3.1) and can't find a way to resolve it..
I'm using qtCreator with mingw and the pre-built vc10 dynamic lib files. 
So, here is what I have done till now:

.pro file:

```
TEMPLATE = app
INCLUDEPATH += "E:/opencv/build/include/"
INCLUDEPATH += "E:/opencv/build/include/opencv/"
INCLUDEPATH += "E:/opencv/build/include/opencv2/"

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_core231
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_core231d
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_highgui231
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_highgui231d
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_imgproc231
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_imgproc231d
win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_calib3d231
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../opencv/build/x86/vc10/lib/ -lopencv_calib3d231d
...
```

I have tested an application that used highgui libs from opencv and it compiled and worked nicely, but when I try to use cvPyrDown(from imgproc_c.h) it compiles but can't load the library correctly it "exits unexpectedly" with code -1073741515.
I don't understand why that is.. as you can see from the .pro file I linked the imgproc libs just like the highgui, but it still won't work!
Any suggestions ?

**Edit**

Ok, the problem is that visual studio creates libraries with different naming conventions than g++ and that's why it won't work.. If this is true, I still can't explain why it works with the highgui libs.. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Opencv is this? I suggest trying latest 2.3, and using CMake instead of .pro files, which is the build system for the overall project.

Then you just file->open-project on the CMakeLists.txt, and you can just look at how examples are set up with CMake.

If this *is* latest, then 1) highgui uses QT so it makes sense that it might play nicer with qt creator and 2) building with .pro on windows might be untested; a unavoidable need for CMake would not be surprising.

**Edit**:   Look at the CMakeLists.txt files for the libraries ....

```
# CMakeLists.txt for /modules/highgui
 #YV
if (HAVE_QT)
if (HAVE_QT_OPENGL)
    set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
endif()
INCLUDE(${QT_USE_FILE})

SET(_RCCS_FILES src/window_QT.qrc)
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(_RCC_OUTFILES ${_RCCS_FILES})

SET(_MOC_HEADERS src/window_QT.h )
QT4_WRAP_CPP(_MOC_OUTFILES ${_MOC_HEADERS})

set(HIGHGUI_LIBRARIES ${HIGHGUI_LIBRARIES} ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTTEST_LIBRARY})
set(highgui_srcs ${highgui_srcs} src/window_QT.cpp ${_MOC_OUTFILES} ${_RCC_OUTFILES} )
endif()

if(WIN32)
   if(NOT HAVE_QT)
      set(highgui_srcs ${highgui_srcs} src/window_w32.cpp)
   endif()
  set(highgui_srcs ${highgui_srcs} src/cap_vfw.cpp src/cap_cmu.cpp   src/cap_dshow.cpp)
   if(HAVE_MIL)

    set(highgui_srcs ${highgui_srcs} src/cap_mil.cpp)
endif()
endif()

if(UNIX)
if(NOT HAVE_QT)        
    if(HAVE_GTK)
        set(highgui_srcs ${highgui_srcs} src/window_gtk.cpp)
    endif()
endif()
 ....
endif()
```

But "imgproc"'s CMakeLists.txt doesn't do any specific checks ... just passes the buck to main opencv lib:

```
 define_opencv_module(imgproc opencv_core)
```

Comment: I'm using the latest version of opencv(2.3.1). Does it really matter if highgui uses qt if the library is built with msvc(that uses another naming convention than g++)?

Comment: probably. you should really rebuild opencv with mingw ... also use cmake, not qmake... that's what OpenCV is tested/developed with, you're putting up unnecessary obstacles for yourself if you insist on qmake.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be using the MSVC version of Qt then?

Comment: Mingw should be able to handle it.. (It works with the highgui libs..)