# Which C++ GUI library should I use

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

I'm developing a segmentation tool (for research purpose, not for commercial use) and I was wondering which graphical user interface should I use as there are many.
I'm looking for a relatively simple interface which allows me to do as follows on the same window:

*Input variables that will be used by the algorithm
*Browse a folder and select images
*Call functions by clicking on a button
*Display an image that will evolve while the algorithm is running

I'm coding in c++ with visual studio 2010 and I'm using additional libraries such as OpenCV, so the GUI library must be compilable and usable on console project on VS2010.
So far I've tried Qt, FLTK, GTK+ but Qt as compatible issues on x64 architectures, FLTK is lacking documentation and I'm not sure it answers to my needs and GTK+ wasn't working.

Thank you very much for any input and help you can give me.

Comment: What's your problem with Qt on X64?  Have you asked questions to try and get it resolved?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176048/qt-application-64-bit-windows

Comment: Also...if you want a console project with a GUI, that's a bit of a trick all around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493536/can-one-executable-be-both-a-console-and-gui-app

Comment: @HostileFork - I was having linking problems, when I looked into it, I saw that it was very common and that there was no way around. I'll take a look at your link though, thank you

Comment: I will be using Qt as this link found on your first link explains how to use Qt with 64 bits architectures.  
http://code.google.com/p/qt-msvc-installer/

Comment: Always happy to hear people picking up Qt.  :-)  If you're not using [Qt Creator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) it can be a little more tricky to set up.  But once set up it's usually a very obvious and clean design, with good documentation and support...

Comment: @HostileFork I'm not using Qt Creator indeed as I'm using another additional library (OpenCV), so I'm working with Visual Studio. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In an ideal world, you can use whatever tools you want *(though I personally think it's nice when you can clone and copy installations and give it to anyone without running afoul of the law or crazy DRM crippleware)*.  But AFAIK there's nothing stopping you from [using Qt Creator with OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556228/linking-qtcreator-opencv).  Again, I'd heartily suggest asking the 'net before assuming a speedbump you hit is a foundational problem...!

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple.
If working with C++ on Windows with a "non-express" version of Visual-Studio, just use MFC.

The framework is mature and there are tons of reference, examples and samples on the web (codeproject, codeguru, MSDN, ... )

Comment: Thanks I'm using a non-express version as well. I will look into that.

Comment: Nooooooo!  Don't use MFC!  :-(  There's nothing particularly compelling about the design in this day and age to persuade a new project to use it, and beyond that fact you are tying yourself to Microsoft platforms [for no really good reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121184/is-there-still-a-case-for-mfc).  Qt is far more elegant and has had a steady cross-platform evolution.  Once you try it, you won't want to go back.

Comment: I have some experience with MFC, and "keep it simple" is not the first sentence that springs to mind, when thinking on it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried OpenCV's own highgui?

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/highgui__high-level_gui_and_media_i_o.html

> "While OpenCV was designed for use in full-scale applications and can
>   be used within functionally rich UI frameworks (such as Qt, WinForms
>   or Cocoa) or without any UI at all, sometimes there is a need to try
>   some functionality quickly and visualize the results. This is what the
>   HighGUI module has been designed for."

Also see: [OpenCV and creating GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823534/opencv-and-creating-guis)

Comment: I have tried that but OpenCv's GUI does not allow me to do all I need to do as described in my first post.